# Generate multiple table (For viewing)

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I would like to ask on how to make my table to appear as following:

[image: How it supposed to look like]

But I only manage to get my table to appear like this:

[image: Current appearance of the table]

As you can see, the table is separated according to the different year or semester of when they stored their stuff. It is basically a history storage of that particular person. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make the generated table to attach together for the one with same year and semester instead of separating it. Even the numbering is affected. Below is the code that I have so far:

```
<?php  
include("connect.php");
include("header.php");

if(isset($_GET['invstuview_bag'], $_GET['invstuview_name']))
{
    $get_id = $_GET['invstuview_bag'];  
    $get_name = $_GET['invstuview_name']; 

?>

<br/>
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="view.php">View History</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item-active">Baggage Detail History</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="cssword">Baggage Detail History For <?php echo $get_name; ?>(<?php echo $get_id; ?>)</div>
<div class="container" style="width:70%;"> 
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <?php
        $sql_join = "SELECT student.*,location.*, inventory.*, baggage.*
                FROM 
                    student,location, inventory, baggage
                WHERE
                    student.student_id = inventory.invstu_id AND
                    baggage.baggage_id = inventory.invbag_id AND
                    location.location_id = inventory.invloc_id AND
                    invstu_id = '$get_id'
                ORDER BY inventory_id";

        $result_join= mysqli_query($connect,$sql_join); 

        $prev_year = "";
        $prev_sem = 0;
        $get_year = "";
        $get_sem = 0;
        while($row_join=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_join))
        {
            $counter = 1;
            $prev_year =  $row_join["invstu_year"];
            $prev_sem =  $row_join["invstu_sem"];

            //if the data is of same year and semester
            if(($prev_year!="") && ($prev_sem!=0) && ($prev_year == $get_year) && ($prev_sem == $get_sem))
            {
                $get_year = $row_join["invstu_year"];
                $get_sem = $row_join["invstu_sem"];
    ?>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Baggage Types</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_join["baggage_type"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_join["invbag_quantity"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_join["location_house"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php
                $counter++; 
                echo'</table>';

            }
            //if data is not of same year or semester
            else
            {
                $get_year = $row_join["invstu_year"];
                $get_sem = $row_join["invstu_sem"];
            ?>
                </br></br>
                Room: <?php echo $row_join["invstu_room"]; ?><br/>
                Year: <?php echo $row_join["invstu_year"]; ?><br/>
                Semester: <?php echo $row_join["invstu_sem"]; ?><br/>

                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Baggage Types</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_join["baggage_type"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_join["invbag_quantity"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row_join["location_house"]; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    $counter++; 
                    echo'</table>';
            }
        }
            ?>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
            <button type="button" name="back" class="btn btn-success" id="back" style="width:200px; display:inline-block; margin-top:2%; margin-bottom:1%; background-color: #4CAF50" onclick="window.location.href='view.php'">Back</button>
    </div>

</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Any ideas is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Move these out of the while loop:

```
           <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th>
                <th>Baggage Types</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>

           echo'</table>';
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply. But if I move the statement that u show out of the while loop, that mean the table header will only be generated once. What I want is for the table header to appear according to the year and semester. That mean it will appear more than once. For the case that I posted, it will be twice. :)